Как выровнять весь текст слева?
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout.width(20) << right << "Отчего работать дяди\n\
    Стали лучше поутру?\n\
    Просто им администратор\n\
    Отключил vkontakte.ru!!";
    
    return 0;
}


Так вы хотите выровнять влево или вправо? Что значит ваше "выровнять весь текст слева"?

В C++ и в C компилятор склеивает строковые литералы, написанный подряд. Никакой операции конкатенации не нужно. Выпишите строки стихотворения подряд, каждую отдельным литералом:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout <<
        "Отчего работать дяди\n"
        "Стали лучше поутру?\n"
        "Просто им администратор\n"
        "Отключил vkontakte.ru!!";
    return 0;
}


$ g++ poem.cpp 

$ ./a.out 
Отчего работать дяди
Стали лучше поутру?
Просто им администратор
Отключил vkontakte.ru!!



Или не вставлять никаких пробелов во второй и последующих строках, начиная их с первой позиции...

@Harry, ответы в ответы.

Кстати, вы не обратили внимание на << right <<? Что же на самом деле хочет автор вопроса?

Да это просто дополнение :) Как и вариант с raw string...

Обратил. Не понял. Стёр. В вопросе страсти начинаются с cout.width(20) <<. :)

Станислав благодарю за ответ проблема решена.
